# Special cases in friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

Imagine that 2 objects are stacked. The friction between the objects is higher than the friction between the bottom object and the ground. Is it possible for the top object to be pushed hard enough to slide off the bottom object. The applied force is parralel to the ground, no angle.

I have tried making equtions for this question, but they led to illogical conclusions (like the bottom object sliding faster than the top one). I asked many people and tried researching it but I cannot find a solid conclusion

Comment: It would largely depend on the direction of the push of the top object. Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: The force would push the object parallel to the ground, no angle

Comment: @Jim Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get two cardboard boxes.  Fill one with books, and put it on the bottom.  Leave one empty, and put it on top of the one full of books.

Push the top box parallel to the ground.  The top box will leave the bottom box.

Find a table.  Put a book on a table.  Push the book horizontally.  It will move on top of the table, rather than the table underneath it moving.

Mathematically, each interface will have some coefficient of static friction, $\mu$.  The maximum amount of static friction will be $\mu N$, where $N$ is the normal force the surface is applying.  As long as the total horizontal force on the object is less than $\mu N$, the object will not move with respect to the object below it.

As long as the $\mu N$ of the top-box to bottom-box interface is lower than the $\mu N$ of the bottom-box to floor interface, you'll find the top box slips off.  This happens quite often actually, especially when the top object has less mass.

The opposite can happen if the interfaces are different.  Stack two tires on an ice rink.  The coefficient of friction the bottom tire to the ice is *much* lower than the coefficient of friction between the bottom and top tires.  Even though the bottom-tire to ice interface has twice the normal force (the mass of two tires) than the normal force for the top-tire to bottom tire interface (the mass of one tire), you'll still find that pushing on the top tire causes the whole stack to slide.

Comment: So the case with the 2 tires on the ice rink, would it be completely impossible for the top tire to slide off?

Comment: @Jim basically impossible.  Within reason.  If you struck the top tire really hard and really fast, you could get into some dynamic situations where the inertia of the bottom tire starts to play a factor.  If you're pushing slowly, then the top tire could not slide off because you couldn't exceed the force of friction.

Comment: A related experiment would be the famous [tablecloth trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lK1ci50DUgc) In that case, you manage to move the bottom object (the table cloth) out from underneith the top object (the dishware), hardly moving the top object.  There's a bit of movement due to practical limitations, but it does demonstrate how inertia starts to play a part when you start accelerating the objects really quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, we can consider the friction between the objects to be much greater than that between the bottom object and the supporting surface. So lets assume nearly frictionless conditions between the bottom object and supporting surface (so it can be ignored in the FBD) to simplify the analysis. See the free body diagrams below.

The first thing we note from the free body diagram of object Y is that the only horizontal force acting object Y is the friction force, $f$ exerted by top object X. 
Applying Newton’s second law to object Y

$$f=M_{Y}a_Y$$ Or

$$a_Y=\frac {f}{M_Y}$$

Applying Newton’s second law to object X for horizontal forces

$$F-f=M_{X}a_X$$ Or

$$a_X=\frac {F-f}{M_X}$$

All the forces in the vertical direction will cancel (equilibrium) so there is no vertical acceleration.

At conditions of impending slipping between the objects both have the same acceleration, thus, $a_X=a_Y$. Therefore

$$\frac {F-f}{M_X} = \frac {f}{M_Y}$$ Also, at conditions of impending motion the static friction force is a maximum and is $f=μM_{X}g$. Substituting this into the previous equation and rearranging terms to solve for $F$ to cause impending motion we get

$$F=μM_{X}g(1+\frac {M_X}{M_Y})$$

Checking the equation for the limiting cases:

(1) If $M_X<<M_Y$ object Y will not move, that is, the upper object X will slide over object Y (remembering there is some small amount of friction between object Y and the supporting surface) and the force on object X will approach the maximum static friction force.
(2) If $M_X>>M_Y$ then a very large force will need to be applied to object X for it to move relative to object Y.

Hope this helps.

[image]